# How to Send Request URL withouth LocalHost in front in Electron with TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, localhost, testcafe

I am using TestCafe `v1.8.0` in Electron `v7.1.13` with the testcafe-browser-provider-electron plugin `v0.0.14`.

Everytime I run a test with testcafe and need to get data, the Request URL is always formatted like: http://localhost:55303/randomCharacters/http://api.lvh.me:3000/graphql

I also have been unsuccessful in mocking the request as well. I've attempted to proxy the request via command line and with a custom RequestHook to avail either. I'm not looking to mock the requests as that would defeat the purpose of running our e2e tests.

At the moment, I am simply trying to send a POST request to login on the home page of the application, but the response is always 222 because the request is never hitting the local server (or remote for that matter. I attempted to send requests to our https://staging-server thinking that would avoid the localhost issue, but I was unsuccessful there.)

Is there anyway to get these requests to the server?

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

EDIT: For clarification, I am using Apollo Client and Graphql to send requests.

Comment: Could you share your source code? Theoretically, you just need to send requests to the same URL, regardless of whether you use TestCafe or not.  
  
Paths like `http://localhost:55303/randomCharacters/originalUrl` lead to the TestCafe internal proxy, which injects testing scripts into a target page. You can learn more about how it works under the hood from [this article](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/how-it-works/). Such URL replacement shouldn't be applied to GraphQL requests.

Comment: @AlexeyLindberg Thank you for the response! What specifically are you looking for in the source code: Apollo Client setup or Testcafe test? And when you say, "Such URL replacement shoudn't be applied to GraphQL requests", do you mean the request shouldn't be proxied to TestCafe like the documentation you provided suggests?

Answer (score 0):

It can be that response from your API does not contain required CORS headers: 'access-control-allow-origin': '*'. Please ensure that your API responds with correct headers.

To mock cross-domain requests you should set the `access-control-allow-origin` header as well. Please refer to the following article to get details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html#mocking-cross-domain-requests

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and it turns out my CORS policy were not set on my local express.js server so even though I was trying to mock the response apparently it's still tests out the CORS policy to see if the call complies.

I debugged it by putting `console.log` in the same-origin-policy.js which you will find under node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/xhr/same-origin-policy.js

Turns out the origin of the call coming from the electron browser when on the the rendering side is: `file://whateverpathyourelectronappisunder` so I had to account for it in my server. That solved the 222 error I was getting.

```js
//Cross Origin requests
  const allowedOrigins = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:3001'
  ];

app.use(cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {    // allow requests with no origin 
      // (like mobile apps or curl requests)
      if (!origin || origin.startsWith("file://")) {
        return callback(null, true)
      }    
      
      if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
        const msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not allow access from the specified Origin.';
        return callback(new Error(msg), false);
      }    
      
      return callback(null, true);
    }
  }));
```